# Reset calculated value to 0 using drop down

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function in Javascript that resets a calculated value when a specific option is selected in the drop down of my form. For example:

Which Test Did you Take?

- Test A
- Test B
- Test C

Based on the selected option, I have conditions set which will reveal another set of drop downs. So if someone was to select "Test A", the following set of drop downs would show:

Test A
Submit your score for Speaking:

- Option 1 *(this would have a score of 10)*
- Option 2 *(this would have a score of 20)*
- Option 3 *(this would have a score of 30)*

Submit your score for Reading:

- Option 1 *(this would have a score of 10)*
- Option 2 *(this would have a score of 20)*
- Option 3 *(this would have a score of 30)*

Once completed they get a total score.

The problem I have is when someone changes their option in the "Which Test did you take" question and chooses let's say "Option B" and then inputs their answers, the score is stacked.

I need the Total Score to reset to 0 whenever the user chooses an option for the "Which Test Did you take"

This is how my code is setup right now:

```
var total_score = 0;

var optionA_speak = $('.quform-field-17_109').val();
        if (optionA_speak == 'Option 1') {
            total_score += 10;
        } else if (optionA_speak == 'Option 2') {
            total_score += 20;
        } else if (optionA_speak == 'Option 3') {
            total_score += 30;
        }
```

And it would continue for the other options.

So again, how would I reset the total score whenever the option in the "Which test did you take" drop down is changed or selected?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can check the onChange event. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp And use a function to reset your counter.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I'm not very experienced with Javascript. Would you have an example to show? Appreciate your patience if my question seems silly

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {  
    document.querySelector('select[name="test"]').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        if(value === 'a') {
          // show relevant fields and reset score
        }
        if(value === 'b') {
          // ditto
        }
        if(value === 'c') {
          // ditto
        }
      });
    
    });
```

```html
<select name="test">
  <option value="a">Test A</option>
    <option value="b">Test B</option>
    <option value="c">Test C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What's the code to reset the score? Sorry. I'm really new :(

Comment: Just score = 0 should do it?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the example

```
<select onchange="reset_counter ()">
<option>Which Test Did you Take?</option>
<option value="1">Test 1</option>
<option value="2">Test 2</option>
<option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

The reset counter jquery

```
function reset_counter ()
{
//if calculate values in a div
$('#total').html ('0');

//if calculate values in input field
$('#total').val ('0');
}
```